# AngularJS expression returns wrong value

Tags: angularjs

I think I'm not seeing the wood for the trees right now.
This is my html code, that should show the business hours if the values aren't left empty.

```
<div class="lokalinfo" ng-if="lokal.openBegin != null && lokal.openEnd != null || lokal.openBegin2 != null && lokal.openEnd2 != null">
    Öffnungszeiten:<br/>
    <span ng-if="lokal.openBegin != null && lokal.openEnd != null">{{lokal.openBegin}} - {{lokal.openEnd}}</span>
    <span ng-if="lokal.openBegin2 != null && lokal.openEnd2 != null">{{lokal.openBegin2}} - {{lokal.openEnd2}}</span>
</div>
```

This is how one entry in my array looks like (excerpt):

```
{"openBegin":"11:00","openEnd":"13:00","openBegin2":"15:00","openEnd2":"00:00"}
```

Now openBegin and openEnd are working just fine, but openBegin2 and openEnd2 don't, the expression in the ngIf directive returns false, as if those values were null.

It's probably just some stupid little mistake but I cannot find it ...

Comment: Could you please let us know if the answer solved your problem, if so accept it as the answer.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, they both really really WEREN'T null. But in the end I didn't have to solve it because I was told we didn't need to show the business hours so I just deleted it and didn't waste another thought on it.

Comment: OK, you really should try to find out the problem and solve it for the SO community if you're going to post a question.  Also for future reference, the JavaScript in relation to your question would of benefited anyone trying to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

From the limited code you've provided, it must be because either `lokal.openBegin2` DOES equal null or `lokal.openEnd2` DOES equal null.  Or indeed both = null.

In your javascript debug these two ( console.log(lokal.openBegin2)) and see which one prints null, then find out why.